# Angularjs removes header on http delete request

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm trying to make an http request with method delete to my server and the server responds with 411, Length required. But when I try to set it in my request it seems that angular removes it. This is the code I have:

```
var DELETE = function (url) {
  return $http.delete(url,{
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': 0
    }
  });
};
```

This is what I see when I look at the actual request made:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Referer:    http://localhost:8877/
Host:   localhost:8877
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
```

No Content-Length. Why does it remove it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a body to your request even though an empty one `data: ''`

Comment: Tried it, didn't help, still the same

Comment: Have you tried out to set it through the higher-level `$resource` service?